# RoR 3.2.9: Minor Issue Changing Size of Images Using Carrierwave, wrong # of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, arguments, carrierwave, rmagick

I have searched for quite a bit on this issue and cannot seem to get it to work (stackoverflow, the Carrierwave Railscasts).

First off, I have zero issues uploading the image. That is working fine. Now the image is quite big and I would like to make it smaller. Currently my avatar_uploader.rb file is:

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [50,50]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

After watching the railscasts (even though it's from the 2011), it seems you have to pass :thumb to your view, such as:

```
<%= image_tag(user.avatar(:thumb).to_s) %>
```

This is giving me an error in the browser of:

***wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)***

I'm not even sure it's necessary to have to pass :thumb into your view. Is it?

I know this is a fairly easy fix, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the syntax has changed, since then. When in doubt, consult the [official documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave):

```
uploader.url # => '/url/to/my_file.png'               # size: 800x800
uploader.thumb.url # => '/url/to/thumb_my_file.png'   # size: 200x200
```

or, in your case, probably:

```
user.avatar.thumb.url
```

Comment: Right right, just tried that actually. Not getting a failure but now it's just a default blank image. See attached: http://i.imgur.com/3V766.png

Comment: What does the code for the anchor look like, is it referencing a sane location (and is the image really there)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob: what do you mean by anchor?

Comment: Ha, no problem. Well I mean this is what I have and is producing the 'blank' image on load: `<%= image_tag(user.avatar.thumb.url.to_s) %>` But no I don't think is is referencing a sane location. I'm assuming it's just being stored locally on my computer currently?

Comment: I should have been more clear - I am referring to the tag in the rendered html that is generated by that code.

Comment: You can find it out real fast by using firebug and inspecting the image in question.

Comment: and you probably don't need the `to_s`, as the url is already a string.

Comment: Oh gotcha: here is what it's showing using inspect in Chrome: '<img alt="Thumb_dp4" src="/uploads/user/avatar/1/thumb_dp4.jpg">'

Comment: Is /uploads/user/avatar/1/thumb_dp4.jpg present on the file system, and can you access that url in the browser?

Comment: I can access that dp4.jpg through the app itself (appname/public/uploads/user...), but no in the browser I cannot.

Comment: Try `"/public/#{ user.avatar.thumb.url }"` (although I could have sworn it should take care of that itself...

Comment: `<%= image_tag("/public/#{ user.avatar.thumb.url }") %>` still the blank image :( Tried a few different variations but no go.

Comment: Something weird is going on here... I would try commenting out hte store_dir method, first of all, as it may be interfering. Then, maybe just go through the official guide instead of the outdated railscast, it seem slike other elements have been simplified. Finally, you should them be able to access the file through the browser, even without the image_tag helper being correct, once you can do that, you should be able to adjust your image_tag call accordingly....

Comment: Appreciate all your help so far, going to bed now and will be back to it tomorrow :)

Comment: I've only used Carrierwave with Mongoid, but the way I have it set up, cw_image_url is a property of the model.  I'm assuming that's how it works here...that being said, is avatar a model (seems like it should just be a field with an image url)?  If not, you should be calling cw_image_url on the user.

Comment: Just started from scratch and got it working, think I had something messed up with :avatar_cache, as you don't want to actually put that in your model (when you generate it, that is), but has to be  part of attr_accessible. Really appreciate you helping me out Brad Werth and ryan508.